# I need to average that last four cells of every third column

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to figure out how to average the lasy 4 entries of every other column or convert my working excel formula to google sheets. My issue is half the people using my workbooks use Google sheets and the other half uses excel. So I need to have both. Below are 2 pics, 1st has 2 formulas that both work in excel. It takes the last four cells of every third column i8:ou8 in the row and averages them in F. So in the 1st example F8 is U8+R8+O8+L8 and giving the average. How every, as shown in the 2nd pic, neither one of the those formulas work in google sheets. It only gives what the 4th cell is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Well, I guess since I'm new I can't post images. That's kinda stupid imo. How is someone new supposed to seek accurate help. But anyway. I'll just try to write it out and hopefully add pics after

Example 1: formulas in excel that work

=AVERAGE(N(OFFSET(G8,0,(MATCH(9^9,G8:OU8)-11)+{1,4,7,10})))

or,

=AVERAGE(N(OFFSET(G8,0,(COUNT(G8:OU8)-11)+{1,4,7,10})))

If i have;  I8 =4 , L8 =12 , O8 =6 , R8=18 , U8=8 ; F8 is the result of the average of the last 4 which is 11 [ 12+6+18+8 = 44  then  44/4 = 11] this continues all the way to OU8. So if I enter 10 in X8, the average would move to O8+R8+U8+X8. These formulas do that perfectly in excel. How ever, in google sheets it just give me what the 4th from last of every third is. So in the above , I8 =4 , L8 =12 , O8 =6 , R8=18 , U8=8 ; F8 is giving me 12 since L8 is the 4th to last of every 3rd colum. So I need to either adjust my excel formula for sheets or find a formula that will work for sheets. I've tried about everything I can think of, so I really appreciate any help

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow, few suggestions to improve your post. 1) Please keep the question as succinct as possible. 2) Instead of an image you are more than welcome to share an example google sheets files, which would help others understand your question 3) Please include a google spreadsheet tag to your question to improve visibility.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZQQ3I2ZUG1JtJbNSgWhwE13kGzZcM9lk7_e2G5wLDwI/edit?usp=drivesdk.

Comment: Thank you..above here is a link to the Google sheets workbook. E and F have the above formulas that I stated. How every it's not calculating the way I need it to. E8 AND F8 Should be 11 not 12. The last 4 cells equal 44 and the average of the last for makes that 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the following to average the last four cells every third column

```
= Average(index(G8:8,0,count(G8:8)),index(G8:8,0,(count(G8:8))-3),index(G8:8,0,(count(G8:8))-6),index(G8:8,0,(count(G8:8))-9))
```

**Edit**
To prevent showing errors you can use the following:

```
=iferror(Average(index(G8:8,0,count(G8:8)),index(G8:8,0,(count(G8:8))-3),index(G8:8,0,(count(G8:8))-6),index(G8:8,0,(count(G8:8))-9)),"")
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much. I can't tell ya how appreciative I am. Been working on that for days and you solved it in mins. Great work

Comment: Is there a way to rid of the #NUM if there is not at least 4 cells of data to calculate?

Comment: @Grubby Updated the code to take care of errors, also if this answers you question please mark this as the solution by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. You're awesome! I greatly appreciate the help